# How does one make a horizontal listbox in .NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am working on porting a VB6 application to .NET and one of the desired UI elements is a horizontal listbox. I can't seem to figure out how to replicate this in .NET.

1. Can this be done with basic winforms?
2. How would you replicate this?

Sample:
[image]

The VB6 code that will replicate the above image:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    lst_horizontal(1).FontSize = 6
    Dim iMaxChoices As Integer
    iMaxChoices = 10
    For i = 1 To iMaxChoices
        lst_horizontal(1).AddItem (" " + CStr(i))
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub lst_horizontal_Click(Index As Integer)
    Dim iMaxChoices As Integer
    iMaxChoices = 10

    For i = 0 To iMaxChoices - 1

        If lst_horizontal(1).Selected(i) Then
            Debug.Print ("Item " + CStr(i + 1) + " selected")
        End If

    Next i
```

Weasel words: I can figure out how to replicate this in Silverlight/XAML, but this app can't be done in that fashion.

Comment: It can be done easily in WPF, but in WinForms you will probably have to code the control yourself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is supported in Winforms as well.  Set the MultiColumn property to True, the ColumnWidth property to, say, 15.  Producing:

[image]

Comment: @Hans Passant you could know the reason why?

Comment: @Hans Passant No way, I've seen the edit but don't works for me in a WinForms: `LB.MultiColumn = True : LB.ColumnWidth = 15 : LB.Items.Add("abc") : LB.Items.Add("def")`

Comment: Please stop spamming my post.  Click the Ask Question button.

Comment: oh, thank you for your kindness (...) If I need to make a question just to ask why a (two lines) supposed solution does not work in my case... better no, thanks anyways, I don't disturb you more.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest the `ListView` with `LargIcon` for `View` property, It might be a good and ready solution for your case.

[image]

Good luck!